# Multi-level filters in Python DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

Consider the following Pandas dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd

products = [{'SKU': 'XYZ1', 'Category': 'A', 'Sub_Category': 'A1', 'Color': 'Red'},
            {'SKU': 'XYZ2', 'Category': 'A', 'Sub_Category': 'A2', 'Color': 'Red'},
            {'SKU': 'XYZ3', 'Category': 'A', 'Sub_Category': 'A2', 'Color': 'BLACK'},
            {'SKU': 'ABC1', 'Category': 'B', 'Sub_Category': 'B1', 'Color': 'Red'},
            {'SKU': 'ABC2', 'Category': 'B', 'Sub_Category': 'B1', 'Color': 'BLACK'},
            {'SKU': 'ABC3', 'Category': 'B', 'Sub_Category': 'B2', 'Color': 'BLACK'}]

df = pd.DataFrame(products)
```

Each SKU in product is unique, and is mapped to hierarchies (e.g. Category/Subcategory) as well as attributes, e.g. Color

I want to understand how to be able to filter SKUs based on filters on the product master data. If no options are provided for any level of the hierarchy/attribute, consider all options as permitted.

e.g.

All Products where Category = ['A', 'B'] (either A or B)

All products where Sub_Category = ['B1'] and Color = ['Red', 'Black'] (a B1 that is either Red or Black)

thanks!

Comment: Thanks much for the advise on query, something to read up. What I'm also looking for is a more generalised method that can work with any query string, e.g. get_products(Category=["A"], Color=["Red"]) and get_products(SubCategory=["B1") -- I want them to be evaluated in the same function. I can code it up with a bunch of if else statements, but what would be the Pythonic way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can [`query`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.query.html) your dataframe:

```
L1 = ['A', 'B']
L2 = ['Red', 'BLACK']

res1 = df.query('Category in @L1')
res2 = df.query('Sub_Category == "B1" and Color in @L2')
```

Comment: what `@`  stands for here in `@L1`,  i understand its referring to a variable.

Comment: As per the docs: `The query string to evaluate. You can refer to variables in the environment by prefixing them with an ‘@’ character like @a + b.`

Comment: thnx @jpp , my +1 .

Comment: Nevered used query before ;)

Answer (score 1):

For your first filter. Select tegory A or B you have to use:

```
df[(df['Category'] == 'A') | (df['Category'] == 'B')]
```

For the second one:

```
df[(df['Sub_Category'] == 'B1') & ((df['Color'] == 'Red') | (df['Color'] == 'BLACK'))]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> df
  Category  Color   SKU Sub_Category
0        A    Red  XYZ1           A1
1        A    Red  XYZ2           A2
2        A  BLACK  XYZ3           A2
3        B    Red  ABC1           B1
4        B  BLACK  ABC2           B1
5        B  BLACK  ABC3           B2

>>> df[(df['Sub_Category'] == 'B1') & (df.Color.isin(['Red','BLACK']))]
  Category  Color   SKU Sub_Category
3        B    Red  ABC1           B1
4        B  BLACK  ABC2           B1
```

and Filtering the `A` & `B` in `Category` :

```
>>> df[df.Category.isin(['A','B'])]
  Category  Color   SKU Sub_Category
0        A    Red  XYZ1           A1
1        A    Red  XYZ2           A2
2        A  BLACK  XYZ3           A2
3        B    Red  ABC1           B1
4        B  BLACK  ABC2           B1
5        B  BLACK  ABC3           B2
```

Answer (score 0):

When I started using Pandas, I found building and chaining small blocks very useful and readable:

E.g.

```
#1. Select Category A or B: Pandas uses | for or and & for and.

categoryA = df['Category'] == 'A'
categoryB = df['Category'] == 'B'
catAorB = categoryA | categoryB

df[catAorB]


#2. All products where Sub_Category = ['B1'] and Color = ['Red', 'Black'] (a B1 that is either Red or Black).



subCatB1 = df['Sub_Category'] == 'B1'
colorRed = df['Color'] == 'Red'
colorBlack = df['Color'] == 'BLACK'

colRedorBlack = colorRed | colorBlack
subCatB1andRB = subCatB1 & colRedorBlack

df[subCatB1andRB]
```

Comment: this is good you put your experience here but will not be too much of code & variables and somehow will impact performance if you have a large dataset.

Comment: That is true. This is only to help Pandas’ beginners to understand how to formulate thoughts into queries. ;)

Comment: We are beginners at some point, but i'm specially one laddering up into this skill :-)